# Как округлить Decimal?

Tags: bigdecimal

Нужно обрезать нули:

```js
const Decimal = require('decimal.js')

console.log(new Decimal('0.001520000001210501501').toFixed(8)) // 0.00152000
```

Нужно получить `0.00152`

https://repl.it/repls/BluevioletMajesticProcessor

Comment: `toFixed` возвращает строку. Приведите к числу и все будет хорошо

Answer (score 2):

toFixed возвращает строку. Приведите к числу и все будет хорошо

```
const Decimal = require('decimal.js')

console.log(new Decimal('0.001520000001210501501').toFixed(8)) // "0.00152000"

console.log(parseFloat(new Decimal('0.001520000001210501501').toFixed(8))) // 0.00152
```